# Unable to upload file with Vue.js and Axios

Tags: javascript, java, rest, vue.js, axios

I am tying to upload a file to a Java back end using axios and vue.js. I know the back end works well because if I use this curl command I can reach it without any problem.

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8081/steg/aaa' --form 'file=@"/home/mycomputer/Files/image.png"' -o result.png
```

But when try to do the same from the app GUI i keep getting a 400 error:

[image]

I don't know why could this be. Here I am adding the code of this component so to see if it matches the behaviour of the curl command:

```
<template>
  <div class="steg">
    <input type="file" @change="onFileSelected">
    <input type="text" v-model="secretText" placeholder="edit me">
    <button @click="onUpload"> Steg</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  name: "Steg",
  data() {
    return {
      selectedFile: null,
      secretText: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onFileSelected(event) {
      this.selectedFile = event.target.files[0]
    },
    onUpload() {
      const formData = new FormData()
      formData.append('image', this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name)
      axios.post('http://localhost:8081/steg/' + this.secretText, formData)
          .then(response => {
            console.log(response.status)
          })
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

So I am not sure what it could be. the curl command works but vue app doesn't. Just in case I am going to upload here just the Java back end code but I think in there everything is ok.

```
    @CrossOrigin
    @RequestMapping(value = STEG_ENDPOINT, method = POST, produces = APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody
    byte[] steg(@PathVariable String text, @RequestParam(value = "file", required = true) final MultipartFile file) throws IOException {

        userInputValidator.validate(file.getBytes(), text);
        return textStegService.steg(text, file.getBytes());
    }
```

The Java debugger does not stop in the Java code, the 400 means it didn't get so far, something is wrong in the request, but I am not sure what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you should use `this.secretText` instead of `this.secretText.value` when build the URL args.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion, I think that helped now I no longer see the 'undefined' but I still have a problem with the header. Please see my update.

Comment: The error on the screenshot is the back-end issue. You are sending requests to `http://localhost:8081` while the front-end is based on a different origin: `http://localhost:8080` (scheme + host + port are not the same). To make it work your back-end is required to send specific headers in the response. Learn more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: I read that and did as you suggested, now on the back end app is ok I no longer see that error but the response is 400. If I do a curl, it works fine but when i use the vue gui doesn't. See the image in my last update. What do i need to do to match that curl request in vue?

Comment: Are we sure that everything here is ok?  axios.post('http://localhost:8081/steg/' + this.secretText, formData). this.secretText is initialized as null. Are you hitting correctly the endpoint?

Comment: @LastM4N I am confident the back end is fine. I actually created a new question to elaborate more. I will accept this one since I no longer have the 400, my issue now is to actually see what I downloaded https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65665026/cannot-open-image-after-being-downloaded-using-axios